# Vuex actions targeting with deep hierarchical data?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Is it possible to structure vuex in a way which I can execute an action like `buildings[0].apartment[1].room[2].dispatch('paint', 'white');`

If not what's the way to go about executing an action targeting something deep in the state?

A global action like `this.$state.dispatch('changeRoomColor', {buildingId, apartmentId, roomId, color: 'blue'})` doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: What are you trying to do, are you trying to pass a deep nested variable?

Comment: My application has objects nested on many levels. I am trying to do things such as loading and updating the state for these deeply nested objects. The application is already in vueify modules and have been passing the data through props which are getting a little messy.

Comment: The folks in the react community recommend normalizing your data. I'll look for a linkInstead of passing a long path like you're doing, you'd pass a room id. `this.$state.dispatch('changeRoomColor', {roomId, color: 'blue' });` Then you'd structure your state like `{buildings: [], apartments: [], rooms: [...]}` and you'd use getters to return denormalized structures.

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html Here is some documentation from the redux docs. I think something similar could be done with vuex.

Comment: @kmc059000 Thanks. So all actions are on a global level? I'll have to think about how to integrate this.

Comment: Yes, all actions are defined at the top level. Any information to describe what needs to be changed has to be passed in the payload for the action. I've definitely done it the way you've done it, but my cases were relatively simple. If I had something more complex, I'd definitely look into normalizing my vuex store.

Comment: Doesn't [modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) solve your problem?

Comment: @CodinCat Yes, I am using modules but the question was about targeting objects deeply nested in the state object. So now I am using namespaced modules like `this.$store.dispatch('rooms/update', payload);` but to access the specific room under an 'apartment' I have to specify the apartment and building. Instead, I am trying the normalized approach suggested above to only provide the id of the room in the payload.